# Workflows - When to use SharePoint (2013), SharePoint Designer 2013, or Infopath Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I've got all 3: Designer, SharePoint 2013, and Infopath 2013.

How do I know if I have to use all 3?  I know SharePoint has a workflow capability, as well as form building.  What are the decision points to know if you have to use Designer and / or Infopath?

Comment: Bueller? Bueller?  Anyone? Anyone?